# my touchpad scroll doesnt work

Tags: windows, windows-8-preview, touchpad

I've installed the drivers for the touchpad but still it doesn't work, I just shifted from Windows 7 to Windows 8, and now my touchpad scroll wont work. can anyone tell me how to fix my touchpad scroll? I'm using a Lenovo g470 laptop

Comment: which laptop / computer?

Comment: Is your touchpad Windows 8 compatible?  Where did you get the drivers from?

Comment: i think its not compatible, since im new to win 8. when i buyed the laptop the drivers are already available in a CD.

Comment: Do you get any error in Device Manger?

Comment: no it doesnt.it also doesnt appear in the device manager.

Comment: http://support.lenovo.com/en_CA/downloads/detail.page?DocID=DS031022&rss=true Hope i helped you!